# Antialiasing in Fragment Shader Three js

Tags: three.js, webgl, shader, fragment-shader

i am writing a small shader that generates a conical gradient in Three.js.
It all works well I have eliminated banding by adding a little bit noise, so in gerneral the gradient looks nice. I only have the problem that on the edge of the 2 gradientcolors i get ugly Aliasing. See image

[image: aliasing problem]

I then tried to smooth the edges im my fragment shader, which works well but not on the very inside of the gradient.

[image: better]

I know I can get away with rendering the scene in a higher res and scale it down or to apply a posteffect but I am wondering if there is a for a nicer approach.

In general I am not an expert in shader writing or three.js, so maybe you have some input to fix this problem in an elegant way.

Thanks for your help, here is a fiddle and the fragement shader code.

[JS Fiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/vabz67L5/1/)

```
<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        uniform vec4 colour1;
        uniform vec4 colour2;
        uniform sampler2D texture;
        varying vec3 vUv;

        void main() {
            precision highp float;

            //get Angle for textureCoordinate
            float angleDeg = atan(vUv.y - 0.5,vUv.x - 0.5) * 180.0 / 3.147;
            if (angleDeg < 0.0){
                angleDeg = angleDeg+360.0 ;
            }

            //Generate Gradient
            float lerpValue = angleDeg/360.0;
            vec4 colour = mix(colour1,colour2,lerpValue);

            //My approach to smooth the edge works well on the outside but
            //not on the inside
            if(lerpValue>0.9995){
                float smoot = 1.0-lerpValue;
                smoot = smoot*2000.00;
                vec4 lerpColor = mix(colour1,colour2,0.9995);
                colour = mix(colour1,lerpColor,smoot);

            }
            ///done with gradient 

            //apply noise from noise texture to eliminate banding
            vec2 textureCoord = vUv.xy;
            vec4 noise = texture2D(texture,textureCoord.xy);
            colour.xyz += mix(-0.05, 0.05, noise.x);
            gl_FragColor = colour;

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Cleaned up fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vabz67L5/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need a more accurate way to compute your antialiasing. An equation which support any value of `lerpLimit` (your magic value 0.9995)

```glsl
    //Generate Gradient
    float lerpValue = angleDeg/360.0;

    float lerpLimit = 0.9995;
    float invDiff = lerpLimit/(1.0-lerpLimit);

    if(lerpValue>lerpLimit){
      lerpValue = invDiff - lerpValue*invDiff;
    }

    vec4 colour = mix(colour1,colour2,lerpValue);

    //My approach to smooth the edge works well on the outside but
    //not on the inside
    // ....
```

Now you can modulate the `lerpLimit` based on the distance pixel/center, in order to have antialias gradient of constant thickness

```glsl
    //Generate Gradient
    float lerpValue = angleDeg/360.0;

    // the constant thickness of the antialias gradient
    // along the seam
    float limit = .02;

    float lerpLimit = 1.0 - limit / (6.283185*length(vUv.xy - 0.5));

    // avoid negative limit at the center 
    lerpLimit = max( lerpLimit, 0.0 );

    float invDiff = lerpLimit/(1.0-lerpLimit);

    if(lerpValue>lerpLimit){
      lerpValue = invDiff - lerpValue*invDiff;
            }

    vec4 colour = mix(colour1,colour2,lerpValue);

    //My approach to smooth the edge works well on the outside but
```

Comment: Hey pleup, really really nice solution. I was working on using the length but I never got the right result.

Thank you for the solution and the nice explanation!